# How to update textField.text with it's search result swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I have a SearchBar Class which inherits from GradientView. I implemented auto-word search based on the entered text. I am fetching the results of the search in to a tableView and showing it under the searchBar. When I select a cell in the search result I want the "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" value to get appended to the already existing text in searchBar.

Answer (score 0):

You should post relevant code for other people to better help you.

The code should suffice what you are asking for based on the information that you've given.

```
func didSelectRowAtIndexPath {
    let updatedText = (self.searchBar.text ?? "") + self.yourArrayName[indexPath.item]
    self.searchBar.text = updatedText
}
```